# Parse Push Notification on Amazon Fire TV only received upon app restart

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-fire-tv

About a week ago, I began noticing my Android app stopped receiving Parse push notifications, but received just one notification (even if there were more than one) upon app restart.

Since then, I've updated to SDK 1.10.3 (from 1.10.1) and I'm still using PPNS 1.10.1 since 1.10.3 doesn't have a PPNS jar and the Amazon Fire OS doesn't support GCM. However, I'm still experiencing the same issue.

Here is the related logs upon app starting up:

```
V/PPNSService: Received request to start service if required
D/com.parse.push: successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.
V/com.parse.PushConnection: PushConnection transitioning from com.parse.PushConnection$WaitStartState@4112f5f8 to com.parse.PushConnection$ConnectState@41150560
V/com.parse.PushConnection: PushConnection transitioning from com.parse.PushConnection$ConnectState@41150560 to com.parse.PushConnection$ConnectedState@419cca40
E/message: {"action":"com.familiair.display.UPDATE_STATUS","old_channel_id":43,"push_hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e","type":"channel","new_channel_id":44}
```

The last log line is my app printing out the message of the push notification, so the device is definitely receiving push notifications, just only the first one on app start. I have been manually sending push notifications from the Push dashboard. The fact that I'm still receiving one push notification upon app start means that there's nothing wrong with the push message and that it's targeting the correct device.

The push dashboard says it successfully delivered the push notification. Before this week, all push notifications were being received on my Amazon Fire TV devices.

Any help would be appreciated.